# Errors installing spaCy on Python 3

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, spacy

I'm using Ubuntu. I installed spacy with

```
sudo pip3 install spacy
```

However, I tried

```
sudo python -m spacy.en.download allpython
```

But I keep getting the error

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the library via different mirrors

```
pip install -i https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spacy
```

or

```
pip install --use-mirror spacy
```

**EDIT**

Local installation

```
git clone https://github.com/explosion/spaCy
cd spaCy
git checkout --tag your_wanted_tag_here
cd ../
pip install ./spaCy/
```

Comment: Your first suggestion gave `You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")`. Your second one gave `no such option: --use-mirrors`

Comment: @user5739619 sorry! It's supposed to be `--use-mirror`

Comment: I then get `no such option: --use-mirror`

Comment: @user5739619 apparently it's still an open issue https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4122. Apprently doing a local install works as edited above

Comment: ok, I just followed all those steps with no problems. I then tried `sudo python -m spacy.en.download all` again and STILL got that `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` error